# Ranking an SQL on 2 Levels

Tags: sql, join, ranking

Okay, another SQL question. What I am trying to achieve is to show by company, which courses their employees have been to, and from there, which is the most popular for each company.
Currently, this is what I have:

> **SELECT** a.corporatename, e.course_title, b.studentID 
>   **FROM** corporate a
>   **JOIN** students b **ON** a.corporateID = b.corporateID
>   **JOIN** studentcoursedetails c **ON** b.studentID = c.studentID
>   **JOIN** classdetails d **ON** c.classdetailID = d.classdetailID
>   **JOIN** course e **ON** d.courseID = e.courseID
>   **WHERE** b.corporateID != '0'
>   **ORDER BY** a.corporatename, e.course_title

This gives me something along these lines:

`corporatename`-----------------------------`course_title`---------------------------------`studentID`
`Deutsche Lufthansa AG Berlin`-----`Airline Security Operations`---------`5`
`Deutsche Lufthansa AG Berlin`-----`Airline Security Operations`---------`6`
`Deutsche Lufthansa AG Berlin`-----`Airline Security Operations`---------`5`
`Deutsche Lufthansa AG Berlin`-----`Workshop on Crisis Management`------`6`
`Deutsche Lufthansa AG Berlin`-----`Workshop on Crisis Management`------`7`
`Korean Air Lines Co., Ltd`----------`Airline Security Operations`---------`8`

From the above, we can see that Lufthansa has sent it's employees to 2 courses so far. Even though `studentID` 5 has been to a particular course twice, because he flunked the first try, it is recorded as 2 entries.

What I hope to attain is this:

`Deutsche Lufthansa AG Berlin`-----`Airline Security Operations`---------`3`
`Deutsche Lufthansa AG Berlin`-----`Workshop on Crisis Management`------`2`
`Korean Air Lines Co., Ltd`----------`Airline Security Operations`---------`1`

I tried to use this code:

> **SELECT** a.corporatename, e.course_title, count( DISTINCT b.studentID ) **AS** total
>   **FROM** corporate a
>   **JOIN** students b **ON** a.corporateID = b.corporateID
>   **JOIN** studentcoursedetails c **ON** b.studentID = c.studentID
>   **JOIN** classdetails d **ON** c.classdetailID = d.classdetailID
>   **JOIN** course e **ON** d.courseID = e.courseID
>   **WHERE** b.corporateID != '0'
>   **GROUP BY** a.corporatename
>   **ORDER BY** a.corporatename, e.course_title

But what I got:

`corporatename`-----------------------------`course_title`---------------------------------`total`
`Deutsche Lufthansa AG Berlin`-----`Workshop on Crisis Management`------`3`
`Korean Air Lines Co., Ltd`----------`Airline Security Operations`---------`1`

it shows me the most popular, yes, but I'd like to be able to compare all ranks.
I'd appreciate any help on this.

Thanks to `bluish`, a simple solution.

> **SELECT** a.corporatename, e.course_title, count( b.studentID ) **AS** total
>   **FROM** corporate a
>   **JOIN** students b **ON** a.corporateID = b.corporateID
>   **JOIN** studentcoursedetails c **ON** b.studentID = c.studentID
>   **JOIN** classdetails d **ON** c.classdetailID = d.classdetailID
>   **JOIN** course e **ON** d.courseID = e.courseID
>   **WHERE** b.corporateID != '0'
>   **GROUP BY** a.corporatename , e.course_title
>   **ORDER BY** a.corporatename, e.course_title

I removed the `DISTINCT` because I need to collect data of all enrollments, not each unique user. Thanks.

Comment: Anyway if you use `count(DISTINCT b.studentID)`, Deutsche Lufthansa AG Berlin - Airline Security Operations will get 2, not 3 like you said you want. Maybe among `DISTINCT` and `3` one is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add also `e.course_title` in the GROUP BY:

```
SELECT a.corporatename, e.course_title, count( DISTINCT b.studentID ) AS total
FROM corporate a
JOIN students b ON a.corporateID = b.corporateID
JOIN studentcoursedetails c ON b.studentID = c.studentID
JOIN classdetails d ON c.classdetailID = d.classdetailID
JOIN course e ON d.courseID = e.courseID
WHERE b.corporateID != '0'
GROUP BY a.corporatename, e.course_title
ORDER BY a.corporatename, e.course_title
```